# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.api'

Tags: python, pip, statsmodels

**the problem**

i install statsmodels success(`pip install statsmodels`),
then i try to import

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\workspace\Projects\Python\ml-demo\demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as sm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.api'
```

**i try to solve it**

`$ pip uninstall statsmodels`

`$ pip install statsmodels`

it didn't work

`$ pip install --upgrade --target="d:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages" statsmodels`

it didn't work

**my environment**

```
$ python -V && pip -V
Python 3.9.4
pip 21.1.2 from d:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

$ pip show statsmodels
Name: statsmodels
Version: 0.12.2
Summary: Statistical computations and models for Python
Home-page: https://www.statsmodels.org/
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD License
Location: d:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: pandas, scipy, numpy, patsy
Required-by:

$ where pip && where python
D:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe
D:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
```

so many thanks

Comment: What happens if you create an empty directory (e.g., c:\temp\sm-test\), cd to this directory, and then either open ipython and `import statsmodels.api` or run `python -c "import statsmodels.tools.print_version;statsmodels.tools.print_version.show_versions()"`

Comment: ‘’create an empty directory“ It reminds me. My project root directory creates a package named statsmodels, so ...

Comment: I suspected as much. Name conflicts unfortunately crest path problems.